# How to get from a tangent space to the underlying manifold?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, tangent-spaces

In a Lie group like $SO(3)$, it is possible to create a tangent space $\mathcal{T}_pSO(3)$ at a point $p \in SO(3)$. The tangent space has its basis vectors, which span a local linear coordinate system.

Using the exponential map $\text{exp}(\cdot)\colon \mathcal{T}_pSO(3) \to SO(3)$, I can map an arbitrary point $q \in \mathcal{T}_pSO(3)$ from the linear tangent space onto the (nonlinear) surface of the Lie group's manifold $SO(3)$. (I imagine this operation as "wrapping" the tangent hyperplane onto the surface of the $SO(3)$ manifold.)

**The question:**

Suppose there is a surface given by the constraint $\mathcal{S}\colon x^2 + 3y^2 - z = 0$. Moreover, let there be a point $r \in \mathcal{S}$ on that surface and let us construct a tangent plane $\mathcal{T_rS}$ at the point $r$.

Is it possible to construct a similar $\text{exp}(\cdot)$ operation for the points on the tangent plane $\mathcal{T_rS}$? In other words: is it possible to come up with a similar function $\text{exp}(\cdot)\colon \mathcal{T_rS} \to S$? How would I proceed with deriving such operation?

Comment: What's your definition of $\text{exp}(\cdot)\colon \mathcal{T}_pSO(3) \to SO(3)$?

Comment: @ArcticChar under that particular $\text{exp}(\cdot)$, I meant the same function mentioned in the "Table I" under the column $\text{Exp}(\mathbf{\tau})$ and row "Rotation" [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01537). I would say it is the Taylor expansion of the $e^x$ function if my understanding is correct (I am an engineering student who is currently trying to fully grasp Lie groups and Lie algebras, in particular $SO(2)$ and $SO(3)$.).

Comment: Thanks. There is one interpretation of the exponential map in terms of Riemannian geometry. I am not sure if it is what you are looking for though.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this topic w.r.t. Riemannian geometry (I am currently reading the Wikipedia article on this topic). What I am really after is a step-by-step derivation of a tangent space (e.g. of a Lie group) and also a step-by-step derivation of the exponential map, which takes points from the tangent space to the manifold. I am confused as to why the $e^x$ function is being used for this mapping. It seems arbitrary to me and without any geometrical intuition at all. That's why I asked this question to see how $\text{exp}(\cdot)$ would be defined for a more difficult surface.

Comment: In the case of the Lie group of unit complex numbers, I can see that the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ makes sense from algebraical point of view (i.e. when the parameter is from $\mathbb{C}$, the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ will split into Taylor expansion for $cos()$ and $sin()$, giving the coordinates for a point on the unit circle). However, it still does not make sense to me from geometrical point of view. And in the case of $SO(3)$, not only I cannot see a geometrical reason for using $e^x$, but I even don't understand why it makes sense algebra-wise.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> In case it helps, if $A$ is a skew-symmetric real $3 \times 3$ matrix, then $\exp(tA)$ is in $SO(3)$ for all real $t$. If $A^T$ denotes the transpose of $A$, the proof amounts to$$\exp(tA)^{T} = \exp(tA^T) = \exp(-tA) = \exp(tA)^{-1}.$$The exponential map in Riemannian geometry comes from following geodesics, and may be viewed as generalizing the Lie group exponential map.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thank you trying to help me. Unfortunately, as a mere engineering student, I do not have a strong mathematical background. My problem is that I do not have intuition for why we should only consider skew-symmetric matrices (why not use e.g. upper-triangular matrices instead?). And I also do not understand why exponentiation should "wrap" points from the tangent space back to the manifold (why not use the function $2.235^x$ instead of $e^x$?). Those constraints seem too arbitrary for me and I cannot see where they follow from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can always construct an exponential map. Given a complete Riemannian manifold $M$, a point $r$ on the manifold and a tangent vector $\xi \in T_r M$, there is a unique geodesic $\gamma_\xi$ in $M$, starting at $r$, with initial derivative $\xi$. The exponential map $\mathrm{exp}:T_r M \to M$ can be defined as $\mathrm{exp}(\xi):=\gamma_\xi(1)$ (i.e. travel along this geodesic for time 1 at speed $|\xi|$, or travel along a unit-speed geodesic in the same direction for time $|\xi|$). This doesn't really have much to do with the exponential map, except in the special case of Lie groups (e.g. the group of invertible real $n\times n$ matrices).

Comment: I think you need to explain how this exponential map in Riemannian geometry has to do with the exponential map in Lie group.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate that you mentioned geodesics. After cautiously re-reading your answer several times, I got an insight that it only makes sense to think about tangents in relation to curves (e.g. geodesics) and that a tangent plane in e.g. $\mathbb{R}^3$ or a tangent hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^9$ (in case of $3\times3$ rotation matrices) at a point $p$ is just the set of the derivatives at point $p$ of all possible geodesics passing through $p$. I'm still deeply thinking about your answer, an if you don't mind, I'll have a few follow-up questions once my brain will be capable of it :).

Comment: For general manifolds, yes. The tangent space is defined in terms of (equivalence classes of) curves, and derivatives of functions along that curve. If you get a chance, I would suggest reading any book that gives an introduction to manifolds, such as chapter 3 of Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds*.